# Counting and deleting repeated digits of array elements

Tags: arrays, c

I need to write a program that allows user to enter an array of integers, finds the digit that appears most often in all entered numbers, and removes it from the elements of the array. If several digits appear the same number of times, the smallest of them should be deleted. If all digits of the element of the array are deleted, that element should become zero. In the end, such a modified array is printed.

Example of input and output:

Enter number of elements of the array: 5

Enter the array: 3833 8818 23 33 1288

After deleting, the array is: 8 8818 2 0 1288

Explanation: The numbers 3 and 8 appear the same number of times (6 times each), but 3 is less, so it was removed it from all members of the array. Element 33 consists exclusively of the digits 3, so that it becomes 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int i,n,arr[100]; n;
printf("Enter number of elements of the array: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("Enter the array: ");
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I'm beginner to programming, and this task should be done using only knowledge learned so far in my course which is conditionals, loops, and arrays. This shouldn't be done with strings.

Comment: I wouldn't think of the numbers as integers, but as strings, and go from there. Their numerical value doesn't seem to be relevant. Each number is entered from the keyboard as a string, and it seems like going round the houses to convert it to an integer, and then extract its digits, when they were given in the first place.

Comment: thank you very much, but this should be done using integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Divide the problem into separate tasks.
2. Write the code

In the code below I do not treat `0` as having digit `0`. It is because it is not possible to remove `0` from `0`. You can easily change this behaviour by changing `while(){}` loop to `do{}while()`

```
int removeDigit(int val, int digit)
{
    int result = 0;
    unsigned mul = 1;
    int sign = val < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    digit %= 10;
    while(val)
    {
        int dg = abs(val % 10);
        if(dg != digit)
        {
            result += dg * mul;
            mul *= 10;
        }
        val /= 10;
    }
    return sign * result;
}

void countDigits(int val, size_t *freq)
{
    while(val)
    {
        freq[abs(val % 10)]++;
        val /= 10;
    }
}

int findMostFrequent(const size_t *freq)
{
    size_t max = 0;
    for(size_t i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(freq[i] > freq[max]) max = i;
    }
    return (int)max;
}

int main(void)
{
    int table[20];
    size_t freq[10] = {0,};
    int mostfreq = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        table[i] = rand();
        printf("Table[%zu] = %d\n", i, table[i]);
        countDigits(table[i], freq);
    }

    mostfreq = findMostFrequent(freq);

    printf("Most frequent digit: %d\n", mostfreq);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        table[i] = removeDigit(table[i], mostfreq);
        printf("Table[%zu] = %d\n", i, table[i]);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PPj9s341b

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm beginner to programming, this is too much complex for me, I don't understand it, If the INPUT is: Enter number of elements of the array: 5; Enter the array: 3833 8818 23 33 1288; OUTPUT should look like this: After deleting, the array is: 8 8818 2 0 1288 this code doesn't make it happen

Comment: `coder` you have 5 repuation, the people trying to help you have thousands of reputation points and don't care about your up vote or answer acceptance. We don't work for you.

Comment: @coder you have everything needed. If you cant even read from the user and print out the result then you should not pass this assesment

Comment: @clearlight `enter an array of integers` - teacher wants integers.

Comment: you are all right, thank you for your amasing explanations

Comment: @clearlight I haven't missed anything from the class, but this assignment is classified as hard problem with arrays, I have done all assigmnts from previous lessons (lesson 1 is conditionals, lesson 2 is loops, lesson 3 is arrays) inluding easy, middle-hard and hard problems. I appreciate this approach but I don't understand what these numbers and tables represent.

Comment: @clearlight it would be so nice if I would have only programming as a subject and if mathematics, linear algebra, physics, electronics wouldn't take so much of my time. thanks for advice, but I wouldn't understand what these numbers and tables do if I would sit for months in front of a computer

Comment: @coder we all had those topics some time ago.